# Bash script in cron job - email when a file has been modified

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I looked at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164383/check-a-files-modified-date-and-email-if-it-has-changed) to write a bash script that checks if a file has been modified every 60 min and sends me an email using ssmtp if that is the case. Here is its content (`monitoring.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -z `find /home/myuser/sites/mysite/logs/nginx/error.log -mmin -60` ]]

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "nothing has changed"
else
    echo -e "Something went wrong!" | ssmtp -vvv myemail@gmail.com
fi
```

I then added this script to an hourly cronjob:

```
 01 * * * * /home/myuser/sites/mysite/logs/nginx/monitoring.sh
```

This does not work at all. Looking at my emails (the sender account that ssmtp uses), the script runs every hour and echoes `nothing has changed` even if the `error.log` file has been modified.

Maybe using `inotifywait` would be more appropriate? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If I run this script manually after modifying the `error.log` file, it works and I receive the email.

Comment: Your problem really has nothing to do with cron.

Comment: I would not use inotify.  I would enable a very explicit auditd rule to tell me who and / or what is changing that file and the exact time it happens.  You could use auditd plugins to send you the alert, or send it to syslog with the audisp plugin and have monitoring tools alert you.

Comment: I think you want single `[`, not double (you're doing a test(1), you're not doing math.

Answer (score 2):

The `-mmin` option as you used it matches an *exact* number of minutes, not a "within this range" number of minutes. See this example:

```
$ touch foo
$ find . -mmin 1
.
./foo
$ find . -mmin 10
$
```

What you want is to use a value of `-10` instead of `10`:

```
$ touch foo
$ find . -mmin -10
.
./foo
```

And you'll probably want to give it the `-type` flag as well to only match files, not directories:

```
$ find . -type f -mmin -10
./foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Correct me if I am wrong but since I cannot specify a range, this type of script won't work for me since I do not know when the file will be modified?

Comment: Well, if you're running this every 10 minutes, you'd check for files modified in the last 10 minutes. I would perhaps recommend a different approach, though. Take an md5 of the file, write it to disk somewhere, then check that md5 on the next run. If the md5 of the file is different, send an alert. This method is much more foolproof than a time-based approach.

Comment: and this (checksum verification) is already provided f.e. by the tool "tripwire", just if you want to have an already working solution for exactly that issue.

Comment: @EEAA thanks, looking into this. Dennis Nolte, thank you, also looked at tripwire but not entirely sure how to proceed with that.